# Run the socket connection in the react native when app is killed in background

Tags: react-native, push-notification, spring-websocket

To achieve push notification functionality I am using spring web sockets in back-end and react native plugin in front-end.
Every thing is working fine in foreground and background.
But I my socket connection is lost when the app is killed by user from the background and I am not getting any push notifications.
Is there any solution for this problem?
How can I keep my socket connection alive even my app is killed in background?
Thanks in advance.
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: which react-native plugin you used in front-end for notification

Comment: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#readme